# Getting text value in selenium via IJavaScriptExecutor

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying  to get some text value in my code using selenium and IJavaScriptExecutor (because of technical reasons I cant use FindElement method)
so Im trying get the text like this :

```
  IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)  ChromeDriver ;
        var a = js.ExecuteScript("angular.element('.ads_builder').scope().textAds[10].contentLine1.display");
```

and its return as null , but when I run this line in web console Im getting the text I need . what can be the problem ?

Comment: You need to add `return` in the script: `js.ExecuteScript("return angular...`

Comment: its working !! thanks !